# cordova add plugin through git command line

Tags: node.js, git, cordova

Trying to add plugin to my cordova project to be able to access file system:

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file.git
```

but I receive an error:

Fetching plugin failed: "git" command line tool is not installed: make sure it is accessible on your PATH.

git was installed as:  `npm install -g git`

how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you installed by `npm -g install git` is not the git command but a utility library to use git in nodejs scripts.

You have to download and install the git program.

Comment: Where I could find the path to git's bin folder?

Comment: Win8. in C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\git there is no bin

Comment: if it's a 64 bits win, it should be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin`

Comment: I don't have `C:\Program Files(x86)\Git` or `C:\Program Files\Git` folder. How come?

Comment: actually I'm sutprised by your install of git from npm. git is not node scripts but an app. may be try to install the app from http://git-scm.com/downloads instead?

Comment: You'r right. Did install it throught http://msysgit.github.com/, thanks. Post the answer.